# Print a chessboard

Tags: javascript, beginner, ascii-art

I'm working through [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html) and just did the examples in chapter 2. One is to create a chess board grid of arbitrary size. My code works, but the if/else if statements I used feel clunky. This is a common feeling I have when I'm writing code, but I'm often at a loss of how else to do it.

How could I write this code in a more compact, elegant way (recognizing the subjectivity of "elegant")?

http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html

```js
var size = 8;
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if(i !== 0 && j ===0){
      result += "\n";
    }
    else if((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 0) ||
      (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 1)){
      result += " ";
    }
    else if((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 1) || 
            (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 0)){
      result += "#"; 
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The resulting board seems to be flawed; only the first row is 8 characters long while all other are only 7 characters long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your code has a little flaw. It will print the first two lines like this:

```
◼◻◼◻◼◻◼◻
◼◻◼◻◼◻◼
```

You may haven't noticed it, because it's hard to spot using a whitespace. This happens, because you use an `else if` after prepending the newline:

```
if (i !== 0 && j === 0) {} else if {} else if {}
```

Remove the first `else` branch it will work.

Personally, I would move this part to the end of the loop, as it reads more like:

> If the line is completed, append a line-break.

This test should be sufficient and is maybe easier to read:

```
if (size - 1 == j) {
    result += "\n";
}
```

To take it even a little further, move this out of the inner loop and get rid of the test at all. As you always are going to append a line-break after each row, this is sufficient:

```
result += "\n";
```

<sup>Thanks to [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) for pointing that out.</sup>

---

Then you want to print a field of the chessboard in any case. So the second test is actually redundant:

```
if ((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 0) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 1)) {
    result += " ";
} else if((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 1) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 0)){
    result += "#"; 
}
```

… can become:

```
if ((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 0) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 1)) {
    result += " ";
} else {
    result += "#"; 
}
```

---

Now, the condition is still hard to read. Let's simplify it:

```
if (0 === (i + j) % 2) {
    result += "◼";
} else {
    result += "◻";
}
```

This looks quite simple already. You can alternatively use the *ternary operator* and rely on JavaScript casting the result to boolean:

```
result += (i + j) % 2 ? "◻" : "◼";
```

---

**The final result**

```js
var size = 8,
    result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        result += (i + j) % 2 ? "◻" : "◼";
    }
    result += "\n";
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `if (size - 1 == j) { result += "\n"; }` should just be moved out of the inner loop.

Comment: @200_success Of course, I totally overlooked it. Even the test is unnecessary now. Thanks for your suggestion, I've already updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> My code works, but the if/else if statements I used feel clunky. This
>   is a common feeling I have when I'm writing code.

To improve code readability and reduce the perceived complexity, you need to reduce nesting, remove conditional branches, simplify if-conditions and switch to a more descriptive style. The following 'techniques' help to simplify your code sample:

1. **Exploit the nested loop structure:** The first `if` condition checking for line-breaks becomes `true` whenever the inner loop terminates. Get rid of the condition and move the statement below the inner loop body:

   ```
   var size = 8;
   var result = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       if ((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 0) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 1)) {
         result += ' ';
       } else if ((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 1) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 0)) {
         result += '#'; 
       }
     }
     result += '\n';
   }
   ```
2. **Remove the redundant `else if` condition:** The final `else if` condition is redundant as it is always `true` when the first if-condition is `false`. Remove it:

   ```
   var size = 8;
   var result = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       if ((j % 2 === 0 && i % 2 === 0) || (j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 === 1)) {
         result += ' ';
       } else {
         result += '#'; 
       }
     }
     result += '\n';
   }
   ```
3. **Simplify the `if` condition:** Your `if` condition can be expressed in terms of both loop iterators and thereby simplified to `(j + i) % 2 === 0`:

   ```
   var size = 8;
   var result = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       if ((j + i) % 2 === 0) {
         result += ' ';
       } else {
         result += '#'; 
       }
     }
     result += '\n';
   }
   ```
4. **Invert the negative `if` condition:** You can get rid of the explicit comparison to zero by switching your `if` and `else` statements:

   ```
   var size = 8;
   var result = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       if ((j + i) % 2) {
         result += '#';
       } else {
         result += ' '; 
       }
     }
     result += '\n';
   }
   ```
5. **Use the conditional ternary operator for terse conditional assignments:** You can replace the somewhat verbose `if else` statements with a single conditional assignment using the conditional ternary operator:

   ```
   var size = 8;
   var result = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       result += (j + i) % 2 ? '#' : ' ';
     }
     result += '\n';
   }
   ```
6. **Replace the declarative loop with a more descriptive approach:**
   Exploit built-in methods and introduce new named identifiers for self-documenting code:

   ```
   function createBoard(size, black = '#', white = ' ') {
     let even = (white + black).repeat(size / 2) + (size % 2 ? white : '') + '\n';
     let odd  = (black + white).repeat(size / 2) + (size % 2 ? black : '') + '\n';
     return     (even  + odd  ).repeat(size / 2) + (size % 2 ? even  : '');
   }

   console.log(createBoard(8));
   ```

Especially the last two changes are subject to personal preferences - some prefer the declarative style, some stick to `if { ... } else { ... }` everywhere - it's your (team's) choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider building the board as a separate concern from displaying the board. I say this as it is more practical from a learning standpoint to understand how you might build the data structure that represents a chessboard (for example a two-dimensional array) not, just how to display it by building a string.  During your programming journey, you will likely learn to embrace the separation of logic/data storage concerns from display concerns.

I would also encourage you to more heavily leverage `Array()` functions.

This might yield something like:

```js
function buildBoard(size) {
    var board = Array(size);
    for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        board[row] = Array(size).fill(0);
        for (var col = row % 2; col < size; col = col + 2) {
            board[row][col] = 1;
        }
    }
    return board;
}

function displayBoard(size) {
    var board = buildBoard(size);
    var output = '';
    board.forEach(function(row) {
        row.forEach(function(col) {
             output += (col === 1) ? '#' : ' ';
        });
        output += "\n";
    });
    console.log(output);
}

displayBoard(8);
displayBoard(20);
```

Now this certainly is not optimized from the standpoint of operational complexity (in that you have to perform \$O(n^2)\$ iteration twice, but it does break down the problem into the logic space of setting up a board and then displaying a board, which has more real-world applicability than building a chessboard directly into a string.